# How to change entire Group Email Address if Domain is Changed in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

We have a Azure DevOps Organization ( couple of projects within the org), all the users in that organisation has been added with email address like @xyz.com and due to the organisation Change the Client has changed their domain from xyz to abc and right now all our email address changed to @abc.com instead @xyz.com but still would like to use same azure devops account. Is there a chance how to achieve this? ( I already went through and looks like , we can remove the user @xyz.com and add new email address with @abc.com ) but, looking for best way to do so.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Azure devops doesnot have user bulk edit feature currently. you have to remove the user and add them back with new email address. You can refer to this [feature suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/338059/add-the-feature-to-bulk-add-users-to-an-azure-devo.html) to submit a new feature request to Microsoft Development team.